# Modular interpretation of the stalks of modular curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms

One may see the modular interpretation of (points of) modular curves in the very first course on modular forms and modular curves. I am wondering if it is well-known that modular interpretation of the stalks of the structure sheaf at points of modular curves, i.e. if $Y$ is an open modular curve parameterising elliptic curves with some level structures and $x$ is a closed point, what can we say about $\mathcal{O}_{Y,x}$?

Comment: If the modular curve corresponds to a torsion-free subgroup, then the completion of the etale local ring at $x$ is the universal deformation ring of the object corresponding to $x$. In general, the completion of the etale local ring at a geometric point of a Deligne Mumford stack is the universal deformation ring at that point. In your situation, the torsion-free condition can be omitted if $x$ does not lie above $j = 0,1728$, though one may have to adjust the moduli interpretation of the point $x$.

Comment: @willchen Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'll make my comment into an answer so this question is no longer marked unanswered.

If the modular curve corresponds to a torsion-free subgroup, then the completion of the etale local ring at $x$ is the universal deformation ring of the object corresponding to $x$. In general, the completion of the etale local ring at a geometric point of a Deligne Mumford stack is the universal deformation ring at that point. The intuition for this is that the unique infinitesimal lifting property of etale morphisms exactly corresponds to the pro-representability property for universal deformation rings.

Thus as long as the etale local ring (i.e., strict henselization of the local ring) at $x$ is the same as the etale local ring of the moduli stack at $x$, then the same statement holds. For example, this is the case if $x$ does not lie above $0,1728$.

Comment: Maybe I have to add more. You said that the (completion of the etale) local ring at $x$ is the universal deformation ring of the object corresponding to $x$. In my question, the object would be an elliptic curve with some level structure (or, its isomorphism class). What is the "universal deformation ring" of such pair?

Comment: @User0829 You can define a deformation functor for any algebro-geometric object, see e.g. Schlessinger's thesis. To this functor you can associate various rings, depending on the properties of the functor. For example, if the functor is pro-representable, then the pro-representing ring is called the universal deformation ring of the object. It turns out that any object whose moduli space is locally Deligne-Mumford has a universal deformation ring in this sense.